# Element missing on IPhone 6?

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have half of elements missing on my bootstrap-based website, on iPhone.
I tested with iPhone 6.

I cant inspect code on the emulator, and I cant seem to be able to find the problem (on normal small viewport inspection on other systems / desktop browsers, elements are there.)

Can anyone help?

website is http://ariarian.net

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if the problem is related to the animation styles coming from http://ariarian.net/wp-content/themes/act/css/animate.css

Difficult to troubleshoot on an iPhone, but if you have laptop Mac Safari on a with a narrow window the result is similar to an iPhone so easier to test fixes with web inspector.

If you play with the `wow animated fadeIn animated` classes in the `orange-section or-section` divs, setting `display:block !important;` it will point you in the right direction.

Hope this helps!